# Is it dramatically more efficient to have less BoxCollider2D's (for raycasting/custom physics)?

Tags: unity, physics

I have a temporary tile system for my platformer where I simply duplicate the same tiny box sprite with a `BoxCollider2D`on it over and over again. Like I said this is a temporary procedure for design testing before I choose something for practical, I don't need it to be the most efficient.

That being said, I'm curious: when using `BoxCollider2D`'s **and detecting them with a custom ray-cast script** is it much less efficient than having a few larger colliders? How much less efficient?

Please back up answers with explanations of source code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some optimizations under the hood that prevent the engine from iterating over the total set of colliders every time it checks: layer filtering, active/inactive flags.

That said, the fewer items in the list of collidable objects that the collision checker has to go through, the faster the processing will be. It's a simple numbers game. It takes less time to check 4 edges of one box than it does to check 4 edges of 500 boxes.

In effect tho, no there will not be a significant speed improvement. There will however be a mild memory consumption improvement (fewer boxes to store).